# Assigning object to interface variable without implementing interface

Tags: java, object, interface, functional-programming

I was just learning about method refernce concept of java 8.What I found strange is the example where a method reference is assigned to the interface variable without implementing the interface, And calling abstract method of interface is calling the method referenced.

```
interface Sayable {
    void say();
}

public class InstanceMethodReference {
    public void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello, this is non-static method.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InstanceMethodReference methodReference = new InstanceMethodReference();
        Sayable sayable = methodReference::saySomething;
        sayable.say();
    }
}
```

Above code prints the message of saySomething method, I am trying to understand how the memory allocation for methods and objects is done here and how overall this works.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Kindly remove "say" from method name "saySomething" and see if it still works or not. What I guess it is just considering to have "say" as the prefix for the method name of which reference you are going to initialize.

Comment: but is this possible to assign any method to any interface variable and then again calling the abstract method of interface, seems very confusing to me.

Comment: @MuhmmadAbubakarIkram doesn't matter, still works !

Comment: Then matching of return type would be the condition. Have you tried changing the return type? I guess then It won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a syntactic sugar to an anonymous implementation or a lambda with a closure (referring to a state outside of the definition, in your case the instance of `methodReference`). Method references and lambdas are treated equally with that respect. So the same memory allocation really.

The use of method references (or lambdas) is possible when an interface has **only one non-static method** and the signature of that method matches that of the lambda or the method reference. In this case the compiler will know how to wrap it and therefore it will be assignable. It does not matter if it is one of "standard" interfaces such as `Function`, `Consumer` or `Supplier` or a custom one, it should be a functional interface that's all.

The following is **quoted** from the [official Oracle Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);
```

The method reference `Person::compareByAge` is semantically the same as the lambda expression `(a, b) -> Person.compareByAge(a, b)`. Each has the following characteristics:

- Its formal parameter list is copied from Comparator.compare, which is (Person, Person).
- Its body calls the method Person.compareByAge.

Comment: Why is it possible to assign that lambda to a variable of type `Sayable`? Shouldn't it be something like `Function` (or the equivalent depeding on return type/parameters)?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think it could be misleading, though, since you might think you're calling `say`, while actually you're calling `saySomething`

Comment: Added response to the answer

Comment: You are calling an implicitly implemented method `say`, which in turn calls `saySomething`. It requires some time to get used to indeed and IMO lambdas would be just enough, that is I find method references superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

While your `Sayable` does not explicitly declare that it is a `@FunctionalInterface`, it indeed is one, as it has exactly one non-static method.

Any functional interface can be assigned a lambda-like expression (such as `() -> printf("bla bla")`) or a method reference (such as  `methodReference::saySomething`). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   interface Rideable {
CarRide getCarRide(String name);
}
class CarRide {
private String name;
public CarRide(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
}

public class Test_QN_26 {

    public static final int MIN = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        //C. (Only one correct):
        Rideable rider = CarRide::new;
        CarRide vehicle = rider.getCarRide("MyCarRide");
        System.out.println("vehicle.toString() "+ vehicle.toString());
    
        

    enter code here
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Here's an example of creating an interface using a constructor refer ::new and it just works. Answers the question